# Answering/accepting your own question ... a Red Flag?

Tags: discussion, reputation, self-answer

I've noticed a number of people on SO who:

1. Ask a question (often very basic), and then
2. Answer their own question, and then
3. Accept that answer as correct.

Thereby giving themselves 15 points. Doing this once or twice might not be a big deal, but I've see users where over half of the answers chosen as "correct" are their own. [Tom Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237690/tom-tom) is the one I am most recently aware of, but there are others. This is ridiculous!

Surely this would be a trivial thing to check for and then ban/limit/something the offenders. I don't give a damn about points, but I do mind wasting my time on these (and related) sorts of people.

I know the subject of Help Vampires, Rep Mongers, etc. has been beaten to death, and I know there are some people here who think there is no such thing as a "stupid question," but it's getting to the point where I am spending more and more time *looking* for a question that is a) interesting, b) worth the effort to answer it. And as a result I am less likely to even return to SO to *look* for something where I can be helpful.

At some point SO itself may simply cease to be worth the effort ... and that would be unfortunate.

Comment: Accepting your own answer doesn't give you any bonus points, while accepting somebody else's answer will at least give you +2 points. So it's clear it's not rep they are after. It *is* perfectly acceptable to answer your own question and accept the answer.

Comment: Oh come on. That's a hardly a red flag. The red flag is repeated poor quality questions. This can be admirably done without providing a single answer, let alone accepting a single answer.

Comment: The user you linked to has asked 58 questions, only three of which were self-answered (and accepted). Additionally, all three of those questions had no other answers, and his answer to one even [helped someone else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416210). So, I don't see anything bad about that... It's actually more annoying (to me) when people post answers to their own question (normally after building off of comments or other answers), but then don't accept *any* of the answers.

Answer (score 11):

<sub>(Some of this is covered in comments)</sub>

1. You don't get the rep bonus for self-accepts, so accepting someone else's answer would actually give them more rep (the +2 for accepting an answer on your question)
2. Self-accepts don't float to the top of the list, so they don't get more visibility (and thus possibly more upvotes) by self-accepting
3. The user with the most self-accepts is [Cheeso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48082) with 57, which is 4.2% of his 1352 questions. The user with the highest percentage of self-accepts is [Jim G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109941) with 19/141, or 13.5%. I don't know where you see

   > users where over half of the answers chosen as "correct" are their own

   The user you linked to, [Tom Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237690/tom-tom), has 3 self-accepts in 64 questions, so he doesn't even appear in the [top 2000](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/11156/)

Comment: Your query counts all posts in "Number of questions", not just the questions. There should be an additional `where PostTypeId = 1` somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

I did this myself this past weekend and I didn't get any rep from it from what I could tell.

I had a problem I couldn't resolve and posted a question. Sometime later, noone had been able to help me, but I'd managed to get the answer by doing more digging. So I posted my findings.

The alternative would be leaving the question unanswered, which would do nothing to help the next person searching for help.